# ListView - reference between adapter and button

Tags: java, listview

A ListView shows hierarchic organized Data. For Example the ListView shows continents. After a click on an the Europe-item of the ListView, we see the Countries of Europe. After a Click on Germany we see in the ListView the federal States of Germany.

The project contains a button too. This button should go a flat higher. For example: if the ListView shows the federal  States of Germany, a Click on the Button generates a View of the countries of Europe in the Listview.
The ListView in my Project works. But not the button. Nothing happens after Click.

The relevant Code:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

… 
//This Code within the setOnClickListener doesn‘t run:
b1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override public void onClick(View v) {
        final ArrayAdapter adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(getApplication(),
            R.layout.activity_listview, treffer);
        adapter.clear();
        adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
        FatherSearch(father);
    }
```

---

More Code of the MainActivity. It runs:

```
final ArrayAdapter adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
    R.layout.activity_listview, treffer);
InformationFetch("v0id0");

ListView listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.mobile_list);   
listView.setAdapter(adapter);

listView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener(){
    @Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int position, long id) {
        String information = (String) adapterView.getItemAtPosition(position);
        father = information;

        int iPosition = information.indexOf(' ');
        String id2 = information.substring(0,iPosition);

        adapter.clear();
        adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
        InformationFetch(id2);

    }
```

The Problem sticks in my view in the order:

```
final ArrayAdapter adapter = new
ArrayAdapter<String>(getApplication(), R.layout.activity_listview,
treffer);
```

I had replaced **this** by **getApplication**, but it works anyway. Apparently it’s about the reference between adapter view and the button.
What can I do? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

please remove this line from **onClick** of button

```
final ArrayAdapter adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(getApplication(),
            R.layout.activity_listview, treffer);
```

because here you are creating new adapter, but not using it anymore.